# In GForge, LDAP Authentication, how do I set the value for the property authenticatedBind?

Tags: php, ldap, forge, gforge

Under the authentication section in this [link](https://gforge.com/gf/project/gforge5/wiki/?pagename=Setting+up+LDAP+integration), it is given for Anonymous search and bind: simply set authenticatedBind to false. Could you please tell me how should I do that?

Answer (score 0):

@esyana **In GForge 6.3.x and earlier**, each of the modules (plugins) in GForge has its own configuration file.  They're all located in /etc/gforge, with the core settings in gforge.conf and plugin-specific settings in the appropriate folder under plugins/.  You'll find the setting ldap.authenticatedBind in `/etc/gforge/plugins/ldap/ldap.conf`

If you update the value there, then run `cd /opt/gforge/bin && php create_config_cache.php` to make the change take effect.

**In GForge 6.4 and newer**, all settings are stored in the database and accessible using a shell script.  Run `/opt/gforge/bin/gf-config set "ldap.authenticatedBind" false` to make the change.  It takes effect immediately.